# Post a json patch in Swift 5

Tags: swift, api, json-patch

I'm testing an api call in Swift with Patch to update an object partially.
It worked well with Postman

```
PATCH http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/eca9c1b05fb24ca192afe370aa5a1965
```

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/firstname",
        "value": "wakaka"
    }
]
```

Here's my playground:

```
let urlString = "http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/eca9c1b05fb24ca192afe370aa5a1965"

let url = URL(string: urlString)

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

//        guard var request = request else { return nil }

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("gzip, deflate, br", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")

request.httpMethod = "PATCH"

let jsonPatch = "[{\"op\" : \"add\", \"path\" : \"/firstname\", \"value\": \"my first name\"}]"

do {
    let encodedResult = try JSONEncoder().encode(jsonPatch)
    print(encodedResult.debugDescription)
    
    request.httpBody = encodedResult
    print(request.httpBody?.description)
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

// decoding
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("err: ",error.debugDescription)
        return
    }
    
    // handling api's errors
    if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print(res.statusCode)
        
        switch res.statusCode {
        case 400:
            print("400")
//            completion(.failure(ApiError.badRequest))
            return
        case 409:
            print("409")
            return
        case 422:
            print("422")
            print(res.debugDescription)
            return
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    // OK
    do {
        let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        print("json:", result)

    } catch let jsonError {
        print("error:", jsonError.localizedDescription)
    }
}
.resume()
```

The result I got:

<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000921320> { URL: http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/eca9c1b05fb24ca192afe370aa5a1965 } { Status Code: 422, Headers {
"Content-Length" =     (
350
);
"Content-Type" =     (
"application/problem+json; charset=utf-8"
);
Date =     (
"Thu, 10 Jun 2021 15:59:29 GMT"
);
Server =     (
Kestrel
);
} }

That weird when it returns 422 while my call on Postman works well. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: With your current way of creating your JSON from a String: `request.httpBody = Data(jsonPatch.utf8)` should make it work. Because `JSONEncoder()` with a String like that will escape again the double quotes.

Comment: Not related to your problem (which I think Larme addresed in their comment) but I suggest you use the triple-quote syntax to include your JSON in your code. That way you can have "pretty" JSON right in your source, which is much easier to validate visually.

Comment: Use a Class or Struct decodable model.

Comment: Thanks, @DuncanC. I tried that way to have the "pretty" json format!